# How to pass function with argument in classname field in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, parameter-passing, jsx, classname

I have following component in my React Project. What I want to do is to Add a className attribute to the `<li>` element. Set it equal to the return value of the getSortByClass() method and pass in sortByOptionValue as the argument.

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

const sortByOptions = {
  'Best Match': 'best_match',
  'Highest Rated': 'rating',
  'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
}
function getSortByClass(sortByOption){
  if (this.state.sortBy === sortByOption) {
    return 'active';
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
}
function handleSortByChange(sortByOption){
  this.setState({
     sortBy: sortByOption
   });
}
export class SearchBar extends React.Component{
    renderSortByOptions(){
      return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
        let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
        return <li className={getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)} key={sortByOptionValue}> {sortByOption} </li>;
      });
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          term: '',
          location: '',
          sortBy: 'best_match',
        };
    }
    render(){
      return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
          <ul>
            {this.renderSortByOptions()}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-fields">
          <input placeholder="Search Businesses" />
          <input placeholder="Where?" />
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-submit">
          <a>Lets Go</a>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default SearchBar;
```

I am getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` after setting the classname field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
....
function getSortByClass(sortBy, sortByOption){
  if (sortBy === sortByOption) {
    return 'active';
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
}

export class SearchBar extends React.Component{
    handleSortByChange = (sortByOption) => this.setState({ sortBy: sortByOption});

    renderSortByOptions(){
      const that = this;

      return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
        let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
        return <li className={getSortByClass(that.state.sortBy, sortByOptionValue)} key={sortByOptionValue}> {sortByOption} </li>;
      });
    }
    ....
```

Pass your state to the `getSortByClass` method as it doesn't have access to `this` because it is written outside the class. Also write `handleSortByChange` inside your class as it is accessing setState from `this`.

Also you can beautify the code as :

```
renderSortByOptions(){
          const that = this;

          return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
            let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
            return (
               <li className={that.state.sortBy === sortOption ? 'active' : ''} 
                   key={sortByOptionValue}
               > 
                   {sortByOption} 
               </li>
           );
        });
     }
```

Comment: Thank you @Ajay Gaur. but I am not still getting the class name active while clicking on the list item.

Comment: Well that's a separate issue. Try debugging that. See if the values you're equating for are equal or not